# Clean Tweets: What are UTF8 and non-UTF8 characters

Tags: r

I am attempting to analyze a corpus of tweets extracted from Twitter.  A number of tweets appear in non-UTF characters.

For example, one tweet is: "Ã¯Â¼Â»Ã§Â±Â³Ã¥â€ºÂ½Ã¯Â¼Â½Ã¤Â¸â‚¬Ã¤ÂºÂºÃ£ Â®Ã£Æ’Â¯Ã£â€šÂ¯Ã£Æ’ Ã£Æ’Â³Ã¦Å“ÂªÃ¦Å½Â¥Ã§Â¨Â®Ã£ Â®Ã¥Â­\ Ã£ Â©Ã£â€šâ€šÃ£ â€¹Ã£â€šâ€°Ã¥ÂºÆ’Ã£ Å’Ã£ Â£Ã£ Å¸Ã©ÂºÂ»Ã§â€“Â¹Ã£â‚¬ Ã£ Â®Ã¦â€¢â„¢Ã¨Â¨â€œÃ£â‚¬â€š   @ShotbyShotorg: How one unvaccinated child sparked Minnesota measles outbreak  \"

I am not familiar with these non-alphanumeric characters or how to convert/exclude these characters.  Are these garbage characters or do they need to be converted?  Thank you.

Comment: These look like UTF-8 characters incorrectly decoded as Latin-1/ISO-8859-1. They aren’t garbage characters.

Answer (score 6):

I found the original tweet: https://twitter.com/narumita/status/476295179796611072?s=21. From this tweet it’s quite clear that the “garbage” text was supposed to be Japanese.

The original text reads

> ［米国］一人のワクチン未接種の子どもから広がった麻疹、の教訓。

Somehow, your text has undergone *two* rounds of mojibake-ification: it was encoded as UTF-8, decoded as Windows Code Page 1252 (CP-1252), encoded as UTF-8 *again*, and decoded as CP-1252 *again*. Unfortunately the text is not recoverable from what you posted since the CP-1252 encoding cannot fully decode all UTF-8 bytes. However, a quick Python script recovers a couple characters, enough to confirm this is how it was corrupted:

```py
t = 'Ã¯Â¼Â»Ã§Â±Â³Ã¥â€ºÂ½Ã¯Â¼Â½Ã¤Â¸â‚¬Ã¤ÂºÂºÃ£ Â®Ã£Æ’Â¯Ã£â€šÂ¯Ã£Æ’ Ã£Æ’Â³Ã¦Å“ÂªÃ¦Å½Â¥Ã§Â¨Â®Ã£ Â®Ã¥Â­\ Ã£ Â©Ã£â€šâ€šÃ£ â€¹Ã£â€šâ€°Ã¥ÂºÆ’Ã£ Å’Ã£ Â£Ã£ Å¸Ã©ÂºÂ»Ã§â€“Â¹Ã£â‚¬ Ã£ Â®Ã¦â€¢â„¢Ã¨Â¨â€œÃ£â‚¬â€š'
print(t.encode('cp1252', errors='replace').decode('utf8', errors='replace').encode('cp1252', errors='replace').decode('utf8', errors='replace'))
```

This outputs:

> ［米国］一人� �ワク� ン未接種� ��\ � �も� �ら広� �� �� �麻疹� � �教訓。

EDITED: A round-trip analysis (taking the original text and badly encoding it twice) revealed that it was likely using CP-1252, rather than ISO-8859-1; the encodings are identical on most codepoints. The post has been edited to use CP-1252 instead.